# How do I set the allowance for ERC20 tokens in Foundry?

Tags: solidity, testing, foundry

In the following minimum viable test I'm failing to mock the allowance so that the ReceiverContract can transfer ERC20 tokens. The expected use-case would be a user (=externally-owned account) interacts with the `ReceiverContract` - if conditions are passed the contract transfers ERC20 tokens from the user wallet to the contract itself.

In this example with DAI ERC20 tokens the test fails with `Dai/insufficient-allowance` (using the mainnet fork mechanism of Forge).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "forge-std/console.sol";
import "openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

    using stdStorage for StdStorage;

contract ReceiverContract {
    address public contractAddress;

    constructor() {
        contractAddress = address(this);
    }

    function sendErc20ToContract(address _tokenAddress, uint256 amount) public {
        IERC20 token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
        require(token.balanceOf(msg.sender) >= amount);
        require(token.allowance(msg.sender, contractAddress) >= amount);

        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, contractAddress, amount);
    }
}

contract TestReceiverContract is Test {
    ReceiverContract testReceiver;

    function setUp() public {
        testReceiver = new ReceiverContract();
    }

    function addErc20TokenBalance(address who, address token, uint256 amount) internal {
        deal(address(token), who, amount);

        vm.prank(msg.sender);
        IERC20(token).approve(testReceiver.contractAddress(), amount);
        uint256 allowanceAmount = IERC20(token).allowance(msg.sender, testReceiver.contractAddress());
        emit log_named_uint("allowance amount from external ERC20", allowanceAmount);
    }

    function testTransfer() public {
        address daiTokenAddress = 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F;
        uint16 amount = 2342;

        addErc20TokenBalance(msg.sender, daiTokenAddress, amount);

        vm.prank(msg.sender);
        testReceiver.sendErc20ToContract(daiTokenAddress, amount);
    }
}
```

What I've tried:

- setting the value in the ERC20 allowance mapping "manually" using `stdstore.target(token).sig(IERC20(token).allowance.selector` -> didn't work
- changing the allowance to different addresses, changing msg.sender in all the places, etc

Is there a bug in my test or is the code conceptually correct? Any hints highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey are you still trying to find a solution to this issue?

```
IERC20(token).approve(testReceiver.contractAddress(), amount);
uint256 allowanceAmount = IERC20(token).allowance(msg.sender, 
testReceiver.contractAddress());
```

vs

```
IERC20(token).approve(address(testReceiver), amount);
uint256 allowanceAmount = IERC20(token).allowance(msg.sender, 
address(testReceiver));
```

Seems that calling into ReceiverContract using `testReceiver.contractAddress()` was the point of failure. Casting the contract pointer as an address returns a valid allowance amount!

Thanks for being my first EthStackExchange issue I've fixed lol! Just started learning Foundry a week or so ago, awfully pleased with it as a testing suite I must say!